# Format date with month name in polish, in python

Tags: python, django, date, internationalization, format

Is there an out of the box way to format in python (or within django templates), a date with full month name in accordance to polish language rules?

I want to get:

```
6 września 2010
```

and not:

```
>>> datetime.today().date().strftime("%d %B %Y")
'06 wrzesień 2010'
```

Comment: Does this mean a grammar-aware `strftime()`?

Comment: I've got similar issue, but I need to parse date instead of format. Due to grammar I've got similar issues with the native Python date functions. 
I've found that there was parse_datetime method(), but it looks that it was removed in 1.* version of Babel. Any ideas?

Comment: It now works as intended: tested today with datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d %B %Y") returning '30 kwietnia 2020'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/ApiDocs/0.9/babel.dates):

```
>>> import babel.dates
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(babel.dates.format_date(now, 'd MMMM yyyy', locale='pl_PL'))
6 września 2010
```

**Update:** Incorporated Nathan Davis' comment.

Comment: Note: Use `d MMMM yyyy` (only one d) in the format string to eliminate the leading 0.

Comment: @Alexandros I updated the answer to use Python 3 syntax. The previous syntax was for Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date

> E
> Month, locale specific alternative representation usually used for long date representation.
> 'listopada' (for Polish locale, as opposed to 'Listopad')

If you want to specify format in your html template then this will do:
`{{ datefield|date:"j E Y" }}`

Answer (score 1):

OP's code now works as he intended: returning '30 kwietnia 2020' and not `30 kwiecień 2020`. Tested today with Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. Setting locale was required, I used the platform one - this might be an issue with web-apps as per other answers.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [cut repeated code]
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 30, 18, 13, 21, 308217)
>>> datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")
'30 April 2020'
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'pl_PL.UTF-8'
>>> datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")
'30 kwietnia 2020'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

datetime.today().date().strftime("%-d %B %Y")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).