# multilingual formatting of date and time in django

Tags: django

In a multilingual Django project, I want to display datefields in different formats, depending on the localization. Inspired by the example given in the [Django documentation on Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/), I would like to use something like

```
def my_view(request, my_date):
    output = _('Today is %(month)s %(day)s.') % {'month': my_date.month(), 
                                                 'day': my_date.day()}
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

where `my_date` is a `DateField`. Unfortunately, this object does not have `day()` and `month()` methods to extract the dates.

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654423/format-date-with-month-name-in-polish-in-python), one respondent suggests the babel module, but then I would have to specify the locale explicitly in the view, which seems like a bad idea to me.

What is the easiest way to present dates on multilingual Django sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#datefield) is represented in Python by a [`datetime.date`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) instance.

[`datetime.date`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) objects have [`month`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.month) and [`day`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.day) attributes. (They are not methods.)

So you can write your view as:

```
def my_view(request, my_date):
    output = _('Today is %(month)s %(day)s.') % {'month': my_date.month, 
                                                 'day': my_date.day}
    return HttpResponse(output)
```