# Parsing python date from string - Polish locale

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, locale, polish

I need to parse polish date from string like this:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'pl_PL.utf8')
print(time.strptime("27 luty 13:00:00", '%d %B %H:%M:%S'))
```

Actually above works fine, but the polish language dates are not as trivial as english one.
The valid date in polish language is this:

```
27 lutego 13:00:00
```

Unfortunately strptime fails printing:

```
ValueError: time data '27 lutego 13:00:00' does not match format '%d %B %H:%M:%S'
```

What's the fool-proof solution for parsing dates from different locales?

Comment: Here's a link to a similar SO question that could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654423/format-date-with-month-name-in-polish-in-python

Comment: (I don't know polish) It looks like "luty" is short for "lutego", and might take the `%b` format, not `%B`?

Comment: My fault, I should introduce the language first. Both "luty" and "lutego" are correct full name for months. 

_Quoting: 'Polish grammar has 7 grammatical cases. Endings of nouns change depending on the number, gender and case of that noun'_

In German there is some sort of similar thing namely: "Deklination der Substantive". In english fortunately there is no such a thing. 

BTW. Tried %b, but it does not work as I supposed.

Comment: According to that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654423/format-date-with-month-name-in-polish-in-python

There is parse_datetime in Babel, but it looks that this method does not exists in V1.* that I use. It was in oldver version. I could find parse_date and parse_time only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookup table:

```
lookup_table = {
    "stycznia": "styczeń",   "lutego": "luty",
    "marca": "marzec",       "kwietnia": "kwiecień",
    "maja": "maj",           "czerwca": "czerwiec",
    "lipca": "lipiec",       "sierpnia": "sierpień",
    "września": "wrzesień",  "października": "październik",
    "listopada": "listopad", "grudnia": "grudzień"
}
s = "27 lutego 13:00:00"
for k, v in lookup_table.items():
    s = s.replace(k, v)

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "pl_PL.utf8")
result = time.strptime(s, "%d %B %H:%M:%S")    # time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=13, 
                                               #                  tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=58, tm_isdst=-1)
```